# UITableView On Screen Image Download Lazy Loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

First of all this is not a duplicate. I have seen some identical questions but they didn't help me as my problem varies a little bit.

Using the following code i am download the images asynchronously in my project.

```
{
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString];
    [self downloadThumbnails:imageURL];
}

- (void) downloadThumbnails:(NSURL *)finalUrl
{
    dispatch_group_async(((RSSChannel *)self.parentParserDelegate).imageDownloadGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalUrl];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:tempData];
        });
    });
}
```

Due to the logic of the program, i have used the above code in files other than the tableview controller which is showing all the data after getting it from the web service.

**PROBLEM:** On screen images does not show up until i scroll. The off screen images are refreshed first. What can i do to solve my problem.

Apple's lazy loading project is using scrollViewDidEndDragging and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating to load the images but the project is way too big to understand plus my code is in files other than the tableview controller.

**NOTE:** Kindly do not recommend third party libraries like SDWebImage etc.

**UPDATE:** As most of people are unable to get the problem, i must clarify that this problem is not associated with downloading, caching and re-loading the images in tableview. So kindly do not recommend third party libraries. The problem is that images are only showing when the user scrolls the tableview instead of loading the on screen ones.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should show your data source code: how do you get the images? if any dependencies with saving the images do exist, when are the data source methods called? before/after saving/downloading the image?

Comment: Its the same project i have sent you earlier in a previous question. Can you kindly look into it? It has become a lot of mess as i am using the Model View Controller Store design in which connection, store and data source files are different but dependent on each other. Thats why i didn't put all the code in the question

Comment: Per your update: I believe your problem IS with downloading, caching, and re-loading the images. Otherwise, why aren't they available for you to set in the cell during cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you have to do is:

1. display some placeholder image in your table cell while the image is being downloaded (otherwise your table will look empty);
2. when the downloaded image is there, send a refresh message to your table.

For 2, you have two approaches:

1. easy one: send `reloadData` to your table view (and check performance of your app);
2. send your table view the message:

   ```
   - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
   ```

Using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is much better, but it will require you to keep track of which image is associated to which table row.

Keep in mind that if you use Core Data to store your images, then this workflow would be made much much easier by integrating `NSFetchedResultController` with your table view. [See here for an example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller).

Again another approach would be using KVO:

1. declare this observe method in ItemsViewCell:

   ```
   - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                 ofObject:(id)object
                   change:(NSDictionary *)change
                  context:(void *)context {

   if ([keyPath isEqual:@"thumbnail"]) {
     UIImage* newImage = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
     if (newImage != (id)[NSNull null]) {
       self.thumbContainer.image = newImage;
       [self.thumbContainer setNeedsLayout];
     }
   }

   }
   ```
2. then, when you configure the cell do:

   ```
   RSSItem *item = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
   cell.titleLabel.text = [item title];
   cell.thumbContainer.image = [item thumbnail];

   [item addObserver:cell forKeyPath:@"thumbnail" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
   ```

By doing this, `cell` will be notified whenever the given `item` "thumbnail" keypath changes.

Another necessary change is doing the assignment like this:

```
       self.thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:tempData];
```

(i.e., using `self.`).

ANOTHER EDIT:

> I wanted to download and load the images just like in the LazyTableImages example by Apple. When its not decelerating and dragging, then only onscreen images are loaded, not all images are loaded at once.

I suspect we are talking different problems here.

I thought your issue here was that the downloaded images were not displayed correctly (if you do not scroll the table). This is what I understand from your question and my suggestion fixes that issue.

As to lazy loading, there is some kind of mismatch between what you are doing (downloading the whole feed and then archiving it as a whole) and what you would like (lazy loading). The two things do not match together, so you should rethink what you are doing.

Besides this, if you want lazy loading of images, you could follow these steps:

1. do not load the image in `parser:foundCDATA:`, just store the image URL;
2. start downloading the image in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (if you know the URL, you can use dataWithContentOfURL as you are doing on a separate thread);
3. the code I posted above will make the table update when the image is there;
4. at first, do not worry about scrolling/dragging, just make 1-2-3 work;
5. once it works, use the scrolling/dragging delegate to *prevent* the image from being downloaded (point 2) during scrolling/dragging; you can add a flag to your table view and make  `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` download the image only if the flag says "no scrolling/dragging".

I hope this is enough for you to get to the end result. I will not write code for this, since it is pretty trivial.

PS: if you lazy load the images, your feed will be stored on disk without the images; you could as well remove the CGD group and CGD wait. as I said, there is not way out of this: you cannot do lazy loading and at the same time archive the images with the feed (unless *each time* you get a new image you archive the whole feed). you should find another way to cache the images.

Comment: i earlier tried something like that. But its too basic. This implementation loads the top ones first and all the way down but at once instead of when user scrolls down just like the lazytableImages example by Apple. How can i have that effect ?

Comment: plus looks like it would have a performance penalty calling reload data each time

Comment: I hope i am not bothering you but again this is another way of doing the same thing. I wanted to download and load the images just like in the LazyTableImages example by Apple. When its not decelerating and dragging, then only onscreen images are loaded, not all images are loaded at once. Can i have that functionality in my project in some easier way?

Comment: I hope there is no performance penalty they way i am loading and caching. I have checked it as the right answer as it has fixed the refresh issue in my project. Rest of the points that you have mentioned for Lazy loading, i will revisit them to implement it in my project later. Thanks a lot again for solving the issue. Much appreciated.

Comment: you might hit some memory limit due to the fact that all images are downloaded at once (and kept in memory all the way through until they are finally archived); on the other hand, the table implementation using KVO is pretty efficient; check with Instruments to see if memory grows a lot while downloading the feed.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), it's great for using images from the web in UITableViews and handles most of the work for you.

Comment: Well i have already completed the downloading of images asynchronously and persisting that data and loading back in. Are you sure SDWebImage library also handles on screen loading of images??

Comment: It does a great job of loading images on screen. No scrolling to get them to load, they just load. Save yourself some time and try it out.

Comment: Man i have already loaded, cached etc. by myself. The question i have asked is different.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Unless you're doing something very unique in rolling your own you'd be better off using an open source solution that many people use. Have you tried calling `setNeedsLayout` on the UIImageView after you complete downloading and set the image?

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is caching the image and use them. I have written the code for table view.
[Image on top of Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267046/image-on-top-of-cell/15268636#15268636)
It is a great solution.

Comment: I have already done downloading, persisting, and loading back in. So i don't requite a library for this purpose. The problem is different.

Comment: the i will suggest you to reload you table every time. Scroll view of table reload your table every time. But i will recommend you to the above link. it cache and load images on scroll automatically. these are simple classes not a big library. try once and you will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading images using this code,

```
 - (void) downloadThumbnails:(NSURL *)finalUrl
  {
     NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:finalUrl];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                     NSData * data, NSError * error)
                    {
                      if (!error)
                       {
                      thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                       }       

   }];
 }
```

Comment: downloading, caching, loading back in etc has been done already. My question was about showing the top images first and loading while user scrolls down